# pandas get count of continuous weeks orders null dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. I wanted to find out continuous weeks drop by country and Product wise from last week(202008).

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'Country': ['UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','US','US','UK','UK'],
            'Product':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','D','D'],
            'Week': [202001,202002,202003,202004,202005,202006,202007,202008,202001,202006,202007,202008,202006,202008,202007,202008],
    'Orders': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Country','Product','Week','Orders'])

df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['Country','Product'], columns='Week',values='Orders', aggfunc='size').reset_index()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

and i wanted below output where it checks from last week and continuous no.of weeks it got null.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: what is the expected answer ? the pivot table code you posted isn't the solution ?

Comment: no. i wanted that text column in my wanted data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, looping by the grouped values and splitting by the week strike:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Country','Product']).size().reset_index()
contiguousWeeks = []

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    current = df[(df.Country == row.Country) & (df.Product == row.Product)].Week.values
    splits = np.split(current, np.where(np.diff(current) != 1)[0]+1)[-1]
    contiguousWeeks.append(len(splits))

df2['CountStrike'] = contiguousWeeks
```

Resulting in:

```
  Country Product  CountStrike
0      UK       A            8
1      UK       B            3
2      UK       D            2
3      US       C            1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this is taking huge time while applying with original data which have 10 columns in group by and 1 million data. so i have edited my question. could you please check.

Comment: The algorithm is linear in terms of the unique combinations of the columns of GroupBy. I'm not sure how it could be optimized. Regarding the text, I'm pretty sure you can find yourself a way to format the result in a string of your choice.